# Mensaje de que no encuentra registro WinForm C# y Sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Estoy realizando un CRUD en WindowsForm C# y usando SQL Server, y trato de hacer que al momento de buscar un registro que me muestre el Message.Box que no encuentra dicho registro. Esto es lo que hecho:

```cs
private void btn_buscar_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

conexion.Open();
            
SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("Select * from pacientes where codigo = @codigo", conexion);
           
 comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("codigo", int.Parse(tb_codigo.Text));
            
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);
           
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           
 da.Fill(dt);
            
dataGridView1.DataSource=dt;
            
conexion.Close();
       
 }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual seria el problema?

Answer (score -1):

Después de rellenar el Datatable, consultas cuantas líneas de resultado obtuviste, si es mayor a 0 existió coincidencia.

```
if (dt.rows.count > 0)
    {
    
    // Codigo si hay registros
    
    }
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).